# copying a given column containing names to another tab if a different column uses a certain word

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am a school teacher that has to keep up with who is allowed to go on a field trip.  On tab one, renamed "8th grade" in column A I have their names. In column M, I write the word "yes" or "no" which designates if they are allowed to go on the field trip.  What I want to happen is, if I type the word yes in that column, I want it to automatically transfer their name from column A to a different tab.

Comment: Once on the other worksheet how will the list of names be used? In formulas, to print, etc? The answer to this opens up possibilities ranging from filtering in place, to using a pivot table.

Comment: Basic it would just be a list. Beside each of the names that now appear in the new tab, I would simply had a column to tell how they paid, another for t-shirt size, etc. So the list of names wouldn't be used in anything basically

Answer (score 0):

The following set of actions are scaled to the number of rows I imagine you might have, at a much larger data size other options might be better suited.

Starting with a worksheet like the following (columns C-K are hidden). The first time you move names you will do it one way, and then a slightly different way to find groups of names that need to be added to the second list. This will keep the second list in order so that new additions do not cause the list of names and the data in cells next to them like shirt size aligned.

[image]

Use filter to hide the rows that do not have a yes in column M. Select Columns A-M by moving the mouse over the letter at the top of the column and dragging.

[image]

Select the names that are left.

[image]

If using Windows press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>. On a Mac use the menu to find "Go To". Once that dialog box comes up click the button labeled "Special..." and select "Visible cells only".

[image]

Copy with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and paste with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> into the appropriate spot on the "Field Trip" tab.

[image]

Now if we will go back and handle any additional names that turn to yes values. Remove the filter from the first sheet and in an empty column add the following formula:

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(A2,'Field Trip'!A:A,0)>0,FALSE)
```

Now we can expand the filter to include this new column and filter for cases where the Field Trip now shows a yes and the onList value is False. Use the same Go To Special Visible Cells and copy and paste the new names below the existing names on the list. In this way you can add batches of names at a time as they become eligible.

[image]

and then with the filters on

[image]